# User cannot see any webparts and content of field person/group

Tags: permissions, user

Only just one user cannot see any webparts of lists and libraries. He also cannot see content of field person/group, even he cannot see who the item create or change, he can see only "create ... by user", "change ... by user" and not name. He has full control permission. He can open open item with url, but all buttons are greyed.
He tryed it on other PC and the same issue. I remove him from site collestion and granted permission again. The same issue he has on any other web application. So it looks like problem with his profile, so I will try to delete him from it. Or does anybody know, what to do?

Comment: are you sure he has access to the list and the items themselves ?

Comment: Yes he has. When I add any content editor webpart on the page, he can see it, but webpart of the list no. I don't use Target Audiences of the webpart.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally when I phoned the user again and he log off from web and then reset all IE settings, the issue was gone. I wrote that he has tryed it on another computer, but now I know that he hasn't set all IE settings by GPO and so when he was trying it, the connection wasn't set...